# Counting lattice points inside an ellipsoid subject to congruence conditions

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be positive integers, and let $Z$ be a positive parameter. Let $M$ be a positive integer, and consider the set of points

$$\displaystyle \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 : Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 \leq MZ, Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{M}\}.$$

Let $N(M;Z)$ denote the cardinality of the set above. How does $N(M;Z)$ compare to the cardinality of the set of integer points inside the ellipsoid $Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 \leq Z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bill Duke*, [**On ternary quadratic forms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2004.06.013), *J. Number Theory* **110** (2005), no. 1, 37--43, [(preprint)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wdduke/preprints/ternary.pdf) gives a uniform estimate for the number of representations of a number by a ternary positive definite quadratic form, which implies the expected answer (that the points in the ellipsoid are equidistributed with respect to $M.$).

Comment: @ScottMorrison Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome. I've been trying out the new citation tool (the little "link" button in the edit toolbar), by occasionally inserting full citations into top-of-the-front-page posts.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Yes, I wondered how you did that, I will try to play with it...